# Angular abstract class HttpClient injection

Tags: angular, httpclient, injectable, injectableprovider

Hi everyone, i'm new with Angular and I am having troubles with Injectable classes.

I have an abstract class (on web.ts) which one of its protected attributes is an HttpClient object. The definition of this abstract class is as follows:

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";


export abstract class Web {
   protected baseURL: string;

   constructor(baseURL: string, protected http: HttpClient) {
      this.baseURL =  baseURL;
   }

   public abstract RetrieveData(pattern: string);
}
```

Then I have another class (on webA.ts) which extends the Web class:

```js
import { Web } from './web';

export class WebA extends Web {

   constructor() {
      super("https://www.test.com");
   }

   private Search(pattern: string) {
      pattern = pattern.replace(" ", "+");
      var searchURL = this.baseURL + `/site/searchpage.jsp?st=${pattern}&id=pcat17071`;

      console.log(searchURL);

      this.http.get(searchURL).subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });
   }

   public RetrieveData(pattern: string) {
      this.Search(pattern);
   }
}
```

Finally, in a class of a component for my website I want to instantiate WebA as:

```js
private webA: Web = new WebA();
```

It tells me that I need to pass an HttpClient object on `super("https://www.test.com");` in webA.ts. To fix it, I can make the constructor for WebA like:

```js
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient) {
      super("https://www.test.com", http);
}
```

But this would lead me to do `private webA: Web = new WebA(this.http);` forcing me to have on my component class:

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

I know there must be another way to do it because in my opinion this is breaking hierarchy on my classes

**TL;DR:** 
I need to "auto-inject" an HttpClient on an abstract class to not to need passing this object as an argument on super in the extender class.

Comment: constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {} should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the constructor in `WebA`

```
export class WebA extends Web {

   //constructor() {
   //   super("https://www.test.com");
   //}
```

or repeat the constructor parameters and forward them with `super()`

```
export class WebA extends Web {

   constructor(baseURL: string, protected http: HttpClient) {
      super(baseURL, http);
   }
```

If you need a constructor in the derived class (`WebA`) the only way is to repeat the parameters and forward them.

**Update**

There is no such thin as auto-inject when you create an instance with `new Xxx()`. Dependency injection works only for instances that Angulars DI creates for you.

Otherwise see my answer above.

Comment: I think his problem is when he wants to `create` the instance, he doesn't want to pass `httpClient` manually. Hi does not inject `WebA`, but creates manually

Comment: @SurenSrapyan thanks for the hint. There is no dependency injection for classes created with `new ...`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thats what i thought to do on first, but as I said it breaks hierarchy. Is there some way to Inject HttpClient on Web abstract class? I dont have neither WebA nor Web on app.module.ts because they are not a component of my app, just auxiliary classes. Maybe I can make angular to inject HttpClient on WebA by adding it to app.module.ts??

Comment: There is no injection for abstract classes. As I mentioned there is only injection for classes Angular instantiates for you and Angular only instantiates concrete classes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I see... Then, i can add `webA` to `@NgModule` on app.module.ts on `declarations []` and `HttpClient` in `providers []`? If I do so it stills says me that I still need to pass http as an argument on `private webA: Web = new WebA();`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Yes, you need to add `WebA` to `providers` and the constructor needs to look like in my answer. Not sure what `baseURL` is. You can't inject a string without `@InjectToken('foo')` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

`"auto-inject"` works only if you want the DI mechanism to create the type for you. In your case I think it is better to declare the class `WebA` as injectable with `@Injectable` and in your class, where you need it just inject `WebA` instance. This way the `HttpClient` will be passed automatically.

```
@Injectable()
export class WebA extends Web {

   ...

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      super("https://www.test.com", httpClient);
   }

   ...

}
```