# Testing an Abstract Class with an HttpClient Dependence in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, abstract-class

I am trying to test an abstract service class that uses `HttpClient`.

To do this I've followed the suggestion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387445/angular-abstract-class-httpclient-injection) by implementing the most basic instantiation of the abstract class, and trying to test that. However I still can't get it to work.

After several attempts, I am currently using code of the form below.

The abstract class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Resource } from './models/resource.model';
import { BaseFunctions } from './interfaces/base-functions.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class AbstractService<T extends Resource> implements BaseFunctions {

  constructor(
    public url: string,
    public name = 'abstract',
    protected http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  get( id: string ): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>( `${this.url}/${id}` );
  }
```

The test code:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { AbstractService } from './abstract.service';
import { Resource } from './models/resource.model';

describe('AbstractService', () => {
  const service_name = 'test',
    url = `/${service_name}`;

  let service: AbstractService<Resource>,
      httpClient: HttpClient,
      httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  let resource: Resource;

  // create class to mock AbstractService
  @Injectable()
  class Base extends AbstractService<Resource> {
    constructor(
      protected http: HttpClient
    ) {
      super( url, service_name, http );
    }
  }

  let abs_service: Base;

  beforeEach(() => {
    resource = {
      id: 'id'
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],

      providers: [
        { provide: AbstractService, useValue: abs_service }
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.get( AbstractService );
    httpClient = TestBed.get( HttpClient );
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get( HttpTestingController );

  } ); // end beforeEach

  afterEach( () => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  } );


  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: AbstractService<Resource> = TestBed.get(AbstractService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });


  describe( '#get', () => {
    it( 'should exist', () => {
      expect( service.get ).toBeDefined();
    } );

    it( `should get ${url}/:id`, () => {
      service.get( resource.id )
        .subscribe();

      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne( `${url}/${resource.id}` );
      expect( req.request.method ).toBe( 'GET' );

      req.flush( resource );
    } );

  } ); // end #get
});
```

This code compiles with no errors, but the tests fail because the `service` is not defined. In other versions of the code I got the `service` to be defined, but either `#get` was not defined, or the `` httpTestingController.expectOne( `${url}/${resource.id}` ); `` would fail. I suspect the latter would fail because I was not correctly injecting the `HttpClient` into the `Base` class.

**Question 1:** Does the order of parameters to the abstract class's constructor matter? (i.e. should the `http` parameter go first, second, third? Does it matter?)

**Question 2:** How do I implement the `Base` class in such a way that I can use the `HttpTestingController`?

Also, if you spot any other errors, or my architecture is completely off, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but you provide your Base service with the token `CrudService`, and then you try to get it from the TestBed using the token `AbstractService`. That's why it's not defined. Why don't you provide and get it, like most services, with the actual class of the service: `Base`?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for spotting those typos. I tried to make an MVE, and missed some of the changes I had to make.

Comment: Now you're using useValue, and passing undefined as value. Use useClass: Base

Comment: That was it! Thanks @JBNizet. If you post as an answer I'll gladly accept it.